# How do I iterate through columns in this dataframe to scatter-plot them as subplots in a grid?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, matplotlib, figure

I have written this for-loop to plot each column in my dataframe as a separate scatter plot. How do I arrange the subplots into a grid?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

y = df['a']

col=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

for i in col[1:]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(df[i], y)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I like `plt.subplot_mosaic` to set up a grid

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using a different method (see edit to my original post), but subplot_mosaic seems like it's got potential as well. I'll have to remember it for next time.

Comment: You are encouraged to [post and accept your own answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out how to plot them in a grid. See Below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')

y = df['a']

col=['b','c','d','e', 'f']

a = 4  # number of rows
b = 3  # number of columns
c = 1  # initialize plot counter

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,11))

for i in col:
    plt.subplot(a, b, c)
    plt.scatter(df[i], y)
    plt.title('{}, subplot: {}{}{}'.format(i, a, b, c))
    plt.xlabel(i)
    c = c + 1
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]